# how to print feature vector shape after each layer in CNN

Tags: python, tflearn

My CNN model architecture is as follows:
def model_a(x_train):

```
input_batch = tflearn.layers.core.input_data(shape=(None, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], x_train.shape[3]))
```

input_batch=tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(input_batch)

```
network = tflearn.layers.conv.conv_2d(input_batch, 32, 5, activation='relu')
network = tflearn.layers.conv.max_pool_2d(network, 2,2)
network = tflearn.dropout(network, .8)

network = tflearn.layers.conv.conv_2d(network, 32, 5, activation='relu')
network = tflearn.layers.conv.max_pool_2d(network, 2,2)

network = tflearn.dropout(network, .8)

network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 256, activation='relu')
network = tflearn.dropout(network, .8)
network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 128, activation='relu')
network= tflearn.dropout(network, .8)
network = tflearn.fully_connected(network,2, activation='softmax')

return network
```

I want to print and save the feature vector shape after each layer and the weights of each layer at the end of the training. How I can do that in tflearn?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the weight and bias values of a layer by using:

> model.get_weights(layer_name.W)
>
> model.get_weights(layer_name.b)

e.g:

```
network1 = tflearn.layers.conv.conv_2d(input_batch, 32, 5, activation='relu')
network2 = tflearn.layers.conv.max_pool_2d(network1, 2,2)
network3 = tflearn.dropout(network2, .8)
// ...
// To get the weights and bias value of the convolutional layer i.e. network1
weight_network1 = model.get_weights(network1.W)
bias_network1 = model.get_weights(network1.b)
```

You can see this [example](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/basics/weights_persistence.py) for more details.